# laravel 5 : Autocomplete Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to make a autocomplete search in my laravel application. But I'm facing a error while I search for the keyword. I got the following error while i see in console :

```
http://localhost/autocomplete?term=a 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the route I have used:

```
Route::get('/autocomplete',[
        'uses'=>'UserController@autocomplete',
        'as'=>'autocomplete'
        ]);
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
  $results=array();
    $item = $request->input(['searchname']);
    $data=User::where('name','LIKE','%' .$item.'%')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
    foreach ($data as $data) {
      $results[]=['id'=>$data->id,'value'=>$data->name];
    }
return response()->json($results);
}
```

And here is the view page with the javascript code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" name="searchname" id="searchname" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
  </div>

 <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#searchname').autocomplete({
            source:  "/autocomplete" ,
            minlength:1,
            autofocus:true,
            select:function(event,ui){
              $("searchname").val(ui.item.value);
            }
      });
   });
    </script>
```

If anyone find what's the error, try to provide the solution please.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: typo in ```public function autocomplte```??

Comment: still same error I'm getting after resolve typo Error.

Comment: try this `$('#searchname').change(function(){
            ...
      });`

Comment: You're using a jquery plugin right? Is it properly loaded?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo here

```
public function autocomplte(Request $request)
```

It should be

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
```

Comment: still same error I'm getting after resolve typo Error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your JQueryui script loaded in after JQuery library?

Comment: Yes I've used it 

 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

     
` <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> `
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>`

Comment: is it before or after normal JQuery? It won't work unless JQuery is loaded first.

Comment: It's inside of `<head>` tag